# Inner case to main where select :-/

Tags: sql

From answers :

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[HardQ3] 
    (@ID_User nvarchar(15), @ID_ListGroupParIzm Integer,@CIzmer Integer, @CPoint Integer, @UserExt bit) 
     AS   

SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT  
         C.ID_ListParIzm, 
         C.Hint, 
         CAST(CASE WHEN T2.ID_Param IS NULL AND T2.UserExt=@UserExt THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as bit) AS Visi ,
         T2.UserExt AS UserExt
    FROM 
         CfgListParIzm C  
         LEFT JOIN 
         (   SELECT 
             T.ID_Param,
             T.UserExt as UserExt 
          FROM
             TbUserParam T
          WHERE
             T.ID_User = @ID_User 
             AND T.ID_Izmerit = @CIzmer
             AND T.ID_Point = @CPoint 
         ) T2 On T2.ID_Param = C.ID_ListParIzm 
     WHERE 
        C.ID_ListGroupParIzm = @ID_ListGroupParIzm AND 
        C.VisibleOnTab=1
        --ORDER BY Num
) d
WHERE (UserExt IS NOT NULL)
```

T2.UserExt IS NOT NULL wont works because Where is working only after select , so I need to use it in real time on selecting for T2 there.

**How to use this case for (T2.UserExt (with inner case)) for each node in main select**

I really hope that question is understatable :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    PROCEDURE [dbo].[HardQ3] 
    (@ID_User nvarchar(15), @ID_ListGroupParIzm Integer,@CIzmer Integer, @CPoint Integer, @UserExt bit) 
     AS   

Select * from (

    SELECT  
         C.ID_ListParIzm, 
         C.Hint, 
         CAST(CASE WHEN T2.ID_Param IS NULL AND T2.UserExt=@UserExt THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as bit) AS Visi 
    FROM 
         CfgListParIzm C  
         LEFT JOIN 
         (   SELECT 
             T.ID_Param,
             T.UserExt as UserExt 
          FROM
             TbUserParam T
          WHERE
             T.ID_User = @ID_User 
             AND T.ID_Izmerit = @CIzmer
             AND T.ID_Point = @CPoint 
         ) T2 On T2.ID_Param = C.ID_ListParIzm 
     WHERE 
        C.ID_ListGroupParIzm = @ID_ListGroupParIzm AND 
        C.VisibleOnTab=1
        ORDER BY Num


)d where  UserExt IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You don't have anything called `UserExt` from your subquery `d`.